# Counting number of 1's and 0's from integer with bitwise operation

Tags: c, bitwise, integer

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
// Definition: Count number of 1's and 0's from integer with bitwise operation
//
// 2^32 = 4,294,967,296
// unsigned int 32 bit

#include<stdio.h>

int CountOnesFromInteger(unsigned int);

int main()
{
    unsigned int inputValue;
    short unsigned int onesOfValue;
    printf("Please Enter value (between 0 to 4,294,967,295) : ");
    scanf("%u",&inputValue);
    onesOfValue = CountOnesFromInteger(inputValue);

    printf("\nThe Number has \"%d\" 1's and \"%d\" 0's",onesOfValue,32-onesOfValue);
}

int CountOnesFromInteger(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned short int i, count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 32 ; i++)
    {
        if (value % 2 != 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
        value = value >> 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Considering the title's reference to a bitwise operator, I was surprised to see `if (value % 2 != 0)` instead of `if (value & 1)`.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, there is a better way:

```
int CountOnesFromInteger(unsigned int value) {
    int count;
    for (count = 0; value != 0; count++, value &= value-1);
    return count;
}
```

The code relies on the fact that the expression `x &= x-1;` removes the rightmost bit from `x` that is set. We keep doing so until no more 1's are removed. This technique is described in K&R.

This approach is superior because it doesn't depend on an integer's size - it's totally portable - and it tests every bit in a fairly efficient way (with the comparison `value != 0`).

Also, you might want to replace `32` in `main()` with `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` so that your code doesn't depend on an integer using 32 bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int CountOnesFromInteger(unsigned int);

int main()
{
    unsigned int inputValue;
    short unsigned int onesOfValue;
    printf("Please Enter value (between 0 to 4,294,967,295) : ");
    scanf("%u",&inputValue);
    onesOfValue = CountOnesFromInteger(inputValue);

    printf("\nThe Number has \"%d\" 1's and \"%zu\" 0's",onesOfValue,sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-onesOfValue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think `and it doesn't have to test every bit` isn't really the truth (it's impossible to solve this problem without testing all bits); the `value != 0` expression is just a fairly efficient way to test all bits (by doing so in parallel).

Comment: Also `the loop will run in time proportional to the number of ones` sounds imprecise as well - the number of iterations of the loop doesn't depend on the number of ones, it merely depends on the position of the most significant one.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Thanks for noting that. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go for a non standard function, because C sucks with bit operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __GNUC__
int popcount(int x) {
  return __builtin_popcount(x);
}
#else
#error Unimplemented popcount
#endif


int main(void)
{
  int x;
  scanf("%d", &x);

  printf("%d\n", popcount(x));

  return 0;
}
```

This will be translated to efficient processor instructions where available, or an efficient library implementation where it's not.

References:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736602/fastest-way-to-count-number-of-1s-in-a-register-arm-assembly

http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins

Comment: Why do you say that C sucks with bit operations?

Comment: For compatibility, I would define `int CountOnesfromInteger(unsigned int value)` { #ifdef \_\_GNUC\_\_ return __builtin_popcount(value); #else /* Your own implementation */ #endif }`.

Answer (score 6):

From a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/1157100):

```
int CountOnesFromInteger(uint32_t i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

This is the best known implementation for the general case.  The [explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation) (see `popcount_3`) is that it works with groups of 2, 4, and 8 bits.

The solution posted by @FilipeGonçalves is best for sparse bitsets.

Comment: Yes! To the interested reader there's a whole chapter on this in Hacker's Delight by Warren.

Answer (score 5):

@Filipe hit the main point I wanted to cover.  But there are some minor improvements that can be made.

---

Remove the `!= 0` for maximum C-ness.

```
if (value % 2)
```

---

If you are not taking any parameters into `main()`, you should declare them `void`.

```
int main(void)
```

---

You don't have any `return` statement, yet you declare that you are returning an `int`.  Let's return `0` at the end of our program to indicate success.

```
return 0;
```

Comment: I believe `main` should also `return` something (`return 0;` is only implicit for C++ IIRC).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Good catch, I've edited that it.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Starting with the C99 standard, the compiler is required to generate the equivalent of a `return 0` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS` if no return is supplied at the end of `main`.